# The generator of $H_n (\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash \{0\})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

$\ \ \ \ \ \ $Let $g:S^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash \{0\}$ be an injective continuous map such that $0$ is included in the bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\backslash g(S^n)$.  I want to prove that $g$ induces an isomorphism of the n-th homology group.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ $I am stuck because the embedding $g$ can be very unusual, for example the Alexander's horned sphere.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ $Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would advise working in homotopy theory and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurewicz_theorem. The hurewicz isomorophism is a natural functor

Comment: @Elad: Thank you but I don't know about the homotopy theory. I can't even prove that this mapping isn't null-homotopy. In fact this problem is an exercise for the Jordan–Brouwer separation theorem in a textbook named "Algebraic Topology: A First Course". So did the writters overlook the difficulty of this problem?

Comment: So what do you know so far? (degree mayer-vietoris)

Comment: @Elad: Yes, I know these elementary contents of singular homology.

Comment: If this comment won't be helpful I will write a complete answer later. Around 0 you have a sphere of radius $r$ small enough such that it won't intersect with the image. Now build a homotopy to that sphere  $rg(x)/|g(x)|$(this will be surjective on the sphere why?). Think of how you subdivide the image to cycles such that one homotopy to the small sphere and the others are contractible

Comment: You speak about "the bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus g(S^n)$". What techniques did you learn for proving the existence of a unique bounded component? The reason I ask is because these same techniques may yield the answer to your question.

Comment: Related question: is there always an arc from $0$ to $\infty$ which meets $g(S^n)$ in exactly one point?

Comment: @Elad: I know one can build a linear homotopy between $g$ and $rg/|g|$. But it replaces the original problem with proving the degree of $rg/g$ is $\pm 1$, which I don't find it easier to solve. I don't think it will be proven just because $rg/|g|$ is surjective.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: I remember we prove it by calculating the homology groups of $S^{n+1}\backslash g(S^n)$. Thank you for your advice. I will think about it.